# a word is zero exponent sum in free group

Tags: free-groups

I read a book about free groups, it says a word is zero exponent sum, but it wasn't defined before. So what is a word which is zero exponent sum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that if you write a word in the free group $F(X)$ over $X$, say, $w(x)=x_1^{e_1}\cdots x_r^{e_r}$ that $e_1+\cdots +e_r=0$. The point is, that a word in $F(X)$ belongs to the commutator group $F(X)'$ if and only if the exponent sum of each element $x_i$ in $X$ is zero. 
For example, the word $x^2yx^{−1}zx^{−1}y^2z^{−1}y^{−3}$ is in $F(x,y,z)'$ (e.g., the exponents of $x$ are $2,-1,-1$),  but $xy^2z^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-2}$ is not.

Comment: This is one of the most delicious, overwhelming facts in free groups: this characterization of their commutator group. +1

Comment: Hello. Where can I find a proof of this theorem you mentioned. That is, a word in $F(X)$ belongs to the commutator group $F(X)'$ if and only if the exponent sum of each element $x_i$ in $X$ is zero. Thanks.

Comment: @bfhaha See question 9 [here](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/aisiit.pdf), page $9$, with solution in the references, Lyndon, Schupp.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Could you provide some reference for "a word in $F(X)$ belongs to the commutator group  if and only if the exponent sum of each element is zero"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I said, the notes on page $9$, with solution in the references.

Comment: @bfhaha I had a similar question regarding the proof of this characterization of the commutator group. For an answer you can also refer to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854291/ways-to-show-that-words-with-exponent-sum-zero-for-each-generator-are-elements-o).